# WD Backup Setup

Tags: windows-10

I purchased a WD Passport Portable Storage Backup drive.  When I run the WD Backup Setup, it indicates "No backup targets found"  It indicates it is looking for either a storage device of cloud service.  The drive is attached and can be accessed using 'file explorer'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install WD Anywhere Backup on your computer, then you can set up a backup to back up your computer to the external WD drive.

There is a full guide on the WDC site [here](http://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=3530).